# Why do the deer and ram share a common root?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, plants-and-animals, linguistics

I am trying to understand the relationship between an אַיִל (ram, Ovis canadensis) and אַיָּל (stag, Cervidae). According to scientific classification these are different families. They seem to share a common Hebrew root in the bible. Yet one is considered a domestic animal and the other wild. What is the reason for their shared *shoresh* (root)?

Comment: Hebrew and Semitic languages do not function this way. Simply take a course in Hebrew or go check out Logos.com. Also, this has already been answered here : https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20763/source-for-tri-or-quadri-literal-roots-of-hebrew-words

Comment: Also, the Bible does not reflect modern science. It reflects the ancient Near Eastern and Greco-Roman worldviews.

Comment: [Paleo] Hebrew originally did not have vowels, only consonants. Context and usage dictated which vowels would apply and so different, unrelated words can share the same root.

Comment: See here by Dr. Brown : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efr-v4vIntc   |  and :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmiZYWRkouk

Comment: My past online professor, Mike Heiser : https://blog.logos.com/2015/05/you-should-probably-stop-using-lexicons

Answer (score 1):

The same question could be possed regarding English animal names like *buffalo* or *panther*? Why did English-speakers apply the term *buffalo* to creatures of diverse scientific classification like the *Bubalus bubalis* and the *Bison bison*? [image: Bubalus bubalis] [image: Bison bison] Or why did English speakers apply *panther* to the scientifically distinct leopards, jaguars, and cougars (*Panthera pardus*, *Panthera onca*, and *Puma concolor* respectively)?

Scientific classification is a clean, zero-overlap system. Languages are messy, and they are changing. So were the words ancient Hebrew speakers used and how they applied them. In short, the answer is that's just how languages work. This might not be very satisfying, but it is true.